# How do I write a Firebase Rule where my trusted server can store a dictionary of objects less than 2 minutes old?

Tags: python-2.7, firebase-security

Here is what I did in python.

```
import json
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from firebase_token_generator import create_token

#FIREBASE EXTRACT
#Using urlfetch because Appengine does not use requests to talk to firebase.
def firebase_leads():
    leads_str = urlfetch.fetch(FIREBASE_URL + 'leads/.json?auth=' +\
                               token,\
                               method=urlfetch.GET)
    leads = json.loads(leads_str.content)
    return leads


def get_pipedrive_person_id(leads):
    person = {
                'name' : leads['FIRST_NAME'] + ' ' + leads['LAST_NAME'],
                'email': [leads['EMAIL']],
                'phone': [leads['PHONE']]
             }
    person_send = urlfetch.fetch(PIPEDRIVE_URL + '/persons?api_token=' +\
                                 PIPEDRIVE_SECRET,\
                                 payload=json.dumps(person),\
                                 method=urlfetch.POST,
                                 headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    if person_send.status_code > 210:
        print 'something is not right with the Pipedrive API. Status code: '
        print person_send.status_code
    else:
        person_content = json.loads(person_send.content)
        return person_content['data']['id']

@app.route('/leads')
def check_for_leads():
    """Get leads dictionary and send it to Pipedrive."""
    leads = firebase_leads()
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    print leads
    for i in leads:
      person_id = get_pipedrive_person_id(leads[i])
      update = pipedrive_deals(leads[i], person_id)
      if 400 < update.status_code > 600:
        return str(update.status_code)
    return str(update.status_code)
```

Here are the Firebase rules that supports for which `leads` is extracted.

```
{
"rules": {
    "leads": {
        ".write": true,
        ".read": "auth.uid === 'lead_checker'",
        "$lead_id": {
           ".read": "data.child('CREATED').val() > (now - 120000)",
           ".validate": "root.child('leads'+'/'+$lead_id).exists() && root.child('leads'+'/'+$lead_id).hasChildren(['CREATED','EMAIL', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME', 'LEAD_DESCRIPTION', 'PHONE'])"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the simulator I do not get to authenticate `.read` for `$lead_id` because it authenticates `auth.uid==='lead_checker'` higher up in `leads`.

How can I authenticate the grandchild of `leads` with `.val('CREATED') > (now - 120000)`?

Also does a `.validate` rule under `$lead_id` work when `.write: true` at the `leads` level?